# Scrapy: Extract links and text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I am trying to scrape the Ikea website webpage. The basic page with the list of locations as given [here](http://www.ikea.com/).

My **items.py** file is given below:

```
import scrapy


class IkeaItem(scrapy.Item):

    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

And the **spider** is given below:

```
import  scrapy
from ikea.items import IkeaItem
class IkeaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ikea'

    allowed_domains = ['http://www.ikea.com/']

    start_urls = ['http://www.ikea.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//tr/td/a'):
            item = IkeaItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()

            yield item
```

On running the file I am not getting any output. The json file output is something like:

```
[[{"link": [], "name": []}
```

The output that I am looking for is the name of the location and the link. I am getting nothing.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you tried "ikea.com" as allowed_domains ?

Comment: @aberna what difference will that make? I'll try that ASAP and no difference. No output.

Comment: It would follow the scrapy example as in the documentation (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

Comment: do you mind sharing the output of scrapy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a simple mistake inside the xpath expressions for the item fields. The loop is already going over the `a` tags, you don't need to specify `a` in the inner xpath expressions. In other words, currently you are searching for `a` tags inside the `a` tags inside the `td` inside `tr`. Which obviously results into nothing.

Replace `a/text()` with `text()` and `a/@href` with `@href`.

(tested - works for me)

Comment: Could you please explain why this works and what I am trying does not?
Basically I want to know how and where I was going wrong. Thanks for the answer. It works. :)

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava updated the answer. Sorry, I'm not really good at explaining things :)

Answer (score 5):

use this....

```
    item['name'] = sel.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
    item['link'] = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
```

Comment: use this and try this tend to be poor things to say in an explanation

Comment: thanks drew, I think these kind explanation goes you up.

Comment: not sure what that means. Trying to help you gain points by good answers.