# Extract all href using css/xpath selectors

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

I'm trying to extract all hrefs on a page.

I have tried the following:
`response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()`
`response.xpath('//@href').extract()`

It's extracting a significant chunk of the links, but not all of them...

More concretely, I'm unable to scrape the twitter link from this site:
https://www.acchain.org/

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: Extract links and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753232/scrapy-extract-links-and-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website uses javascript to generate some of the content, including the sidebar (generated by https://www.acchain.org/js/sidebar.js)

The simplest way to scrape these links would be executing the javascript, e.g. using a browser.
There are multiple ways you could do this, but probably the simplest is using the [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) middleware.

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't faced this problem yet. How did you identify that they're being generated? Thank you!

Comment: I looked at the HTML source, saw that the links weren't there and `<div class="sidebar"></div>` was empty, and noticed the javascript file.

Comment: What do you use to inspect? Because when I inspect the page and search for "twitter" it shows up immediately (thus the confusion).

Comment: I looked at the actual source (Ctrl+U in most browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference of [Scrapy Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U&index=8&list=PLZyvi_9gamL-EE3zQJbU5N3nzJcfNeFHU) to write code for this page since it involves javascript to generate the content of body.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `//a/@href`
Tested on Linux bash with

`xmllint --html --recover --xpath '//a/@href' test.html | sed -e 's/href/\nhref/g'`

Comment: If `//@href` doesn't select a link then `//a/@href` won't select it either.

Comment: @michael-kay as my comment says, it was tested so I'm positive that //a/@ref works.

Comment: The answer from @stranac says it doesn't work because some of the links are not in @href attributes. Basically, the OP was confused about whether they wanted all the "links" or all the `href` attributes, which are two different requirements.