# Python urllib get HTML page requisites

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, wget, urllib

I would like to ask if is there a proper way to retrieve (do not save/download locally) all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page and their information (page size etc.) with python `urllib`? This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

I searched and found that `wget` can perform the described procedure using `--page-requisites` flag but the performance is not the same and I don't want to download anything locally. Furthermore, the flag `-O/dev/null` is not working with what I want to achieve.

My final goal is to hit the page (hosted locally), gather page info and move on.

Any tips, reading references is appreciated.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It's simple to use and you can set an `xpath` to locate and retrieve just the information you need, e.g. inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753232/scrapy-extract-links-and-text) to retrieve text and links

```
import  scrapy
from ikea.items import IkeaItem
class IkeaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ikea'

    allowed_domains = ['http://www.ikea.com/']

    start_urls = ['http://www.ikea.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//tr/td'):
            item = IkeaItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('//a/text()').extract()#change here
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()

            yield item
```

As you can see you can set an `Xpath` to extract just what you want.

For example,

image, `item['link'] = sel.xpath('//img').extract()`

sound, `item['link'] = sel.xpath('//audio').extract()`

And as for hosting locally, it would work just as same, you would simply have to change the `url`. You can then save the data or do whatever you want.